# RegEx [A-Za-z !,?._'@]+ returns 0 matches while [ !,?._'@]+ returns 10?

Tags: java, regex

```
String s = "He is a very very good boy, isn't he?";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(("[A-Za-z !,?._'@]+"));
String[] split = pattern.split(s); 
System.out.println(split.length);
```

Question 1: RegEx `[A-Za-z !,?._'@]+` returns 0 substrings while `[ !,?._'@]+` returns 10. Please explain how removing `A-Za-z` from the pattern resulted in matches?

Question 2: RegEx `[ !,?._'@]+` returns 10 substrings while `[ !,?._'@]` returns 11. Using + and not using + provides different answers, please explain. I understand that + matches one or more. When I sysout the split array, I see that RegEx with + sign considers ", " (comma and space after boy) as one pattern. But without + sign it considers ", " as 2 separate patterns. Does this mean + symbol is used to match one or more combinations of regex pattern?

Please explain above 2 questions.

Comment: Your first *question* isn't a question.

Comment: **`+`** Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible if you have one or more pattern

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how `split` works - it looks for expressions in the string which match the pattern and splits the string around them, removing the pattern in the process. See the [manual](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

In your first example, the regex `[A-Za-z !,?._'@]+` matches every character in the string so `split` returns nothing as there are no characters either side of the pattern.

In the second example, the regex `[ !,?._'@]+` returns 10 substrings as there are 9 occurrences of the pattern within the string: `(space)`, `(space)`, `(space)`, `(space)`, `(space)`, `(space)`, `,(space)`, `'` and `(space)` (the last `?` doesn't generate a substring as there are no characters after it). The output substrings are: `He`, `is`, `a`, `very`, `very`, `good`, `boy`, `isn`, `t`, `he`.

Finally in your third example (`[ !,?._'@]`), the difference is that the `,(space)` which was matched as one delimiter in the second example (because of the `+` on the regex) is now matched as two: `,` and `(space)`. This results in an additional, empty substring in the output.The output substrings are: `He`, `is`, `a`, `very`, `very`, `good`, `boy`, `(empty)`, `isn`, `t`, `he`.

I've created a [demo on rextester](https://rextester.com/LBO40740) which outputs each of the substrings so you can see this in action.